# [Verification of principality]

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I need to find all the ideals of $A=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{a}]$ for an integral number $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. If I can prove that $A$ is principal, I can show that all ideals are generated by an integral number $m$, since $\frac{1}{a}$ is invertible in $A$. I thought of building a suitable stathm over $A$, but there are two interrelated parameters: the power of $a$ and the absolue value over $\mathbb{Z}$, and I'm not sure how to balance between these two... I know that $A$ is noetherian, since it's a $Z-$module of finite type over $\mathbb{Z}$.

How can I prove that $A$ is principal (since I have a strong feeling that it is)? Moreover, what is a generalisation (i.d. what are the principal rings of the same type as $A$)?

Comment: “Stathm “?  “Absolute value over Z”? “Same type as A”? I’m not sure what these are supposed to be.  You mean you want to show A is a *principal ideal ring*?  One does not often say such a ring “is principle” but I know what you mean, I think.

Comment: Sorry for the terminologies... :)

Comment: Same type means "similar"... normal language :)

Comment: what about “stathm “

Comment: it's the euclidean application

Comment: Wow, I have never heard of "euclidean stathm" or "euclidean application" in my entire life. Normally such words (stathm, I mean) at least appear in the dictionary. Internet searches for the word in isolation yield garbage. I wonder what the idea was behind this unfortunate choice of term.

Comment: I went to a French university

Comment: and I'm not even sure which one is the correct writing, stasthm, stathsme or stathme... it's the degree-absolute-value function that permits you to make euclidean division

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that for non-zero $a\in\Bbb Z$, then $\Bbb Z\hookrightarrow\Bbb Z[1/a]$ is a ring localization.
Consequently, there exists a bijection between ideals in $\Bbb Z[1/a]$ and ideals in $\Bbb Z$ which doesn't meet $\{a^n:n\in\Bbb N\}$.
Thus if $\mathfrak b\subseteq\Bbb Z[1/a]$ is an ideal, then
$$\mathfrak b=(\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z)\Bbb Z[1/a]$$
For, the inclusion $(\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z)\Bbb Z[1/a]\subseteq\mathfrak b$ follows directly from $\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z\subseteq\mathfrak b$, while the opposite inclusion $\mathfrak b\subseteq(\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z)\Bbb Z[1/a]$ follows from the fact that every element in $\mathfrak b$ can be written, by bring to a common denominator, in the form $x/a^n$ for suitable $x\in\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z$ and $n\in\Bbb N$.
Since $\Bbb Z$ is a principal ideal domain, then $\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z=b\Bbb Z$ for some $b\in\Bbb Z$, hence $\mathfrak b=b\Bbb Z[1/a]$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyhow, I was trying essentially to prove the passage "consequently,..." in a more elemtary way without invoking any ring-localization-theoretic argument.

Comment: I edit my post to provide an elementary proof of the equality $\mathfrak b=(\mathfrak b\cap\Bbb Z)\Bbb Z[1/a]$.